# Matrix element plot by for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, plot

I heavily doubt my code is correct for this assignment of mine. Below is a short description of the task at hand with some matlab syntax, but do not interpret this as code. My code can be found at the end of this message.

```
M = [100 0;0 10]

K = [k+oa^2m -oa^2m;-oa^2m oa^2m]
```

where `k=8950000`, `m=10` and `oa` varies in a for-loop.

```
A = inv([-(100pi)^2*M+K])
```

The matrix elements `A11` and `A12` is to be plotted in the interval `30pi<=oa<=150pi`. I am then supposed to find where `A11=0`.

The reason I am sceptical about my code (see below) is because the plot does not intersect the x-axis but has more of an asymptotic character (y=0). There is no "clean" `A11=0`. Something interesting also happens at `oa=~69.46pi`. Can anyone find the error(s)? Thanks!

```
M = [100 0;0 10];
A11 = [];
A12 = [];
oav = linspace(0.3*100*pi,1.5*100*pi,10000);
for oa=oav;
A = inv(-(100*pi)^2*M+[8950000+oa^2*10 -oa^2*10; -oa^2*10 oa^2*10]);
A11 = [A11 A(1,1)];
A12 = [A12 A(1,2)];
end
plot(oav,A11,oav,A12)
```

Answer (score 0):

`A11` does cross zero if you zoom enough:

```
>> min(A11)
ans = -0.0079732
```

`69.46 < 30*pi` so `oa=~69.46` is not even in the range you defined...

Comment: I meant 69.46pi. However, I was looking at A12 (facepalm). Thanks!